# How can vector-tensor product be defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Given that a tensor $T$ can operate over a vector $u$ as

$$
Tu = (a \otimes b)u = (b \cdot u)a
$$

Is it possible to define the oposite operation $uT$ ?

Here's what I've got so far... Let $v$ be a vector, then:

\begin{align*}
(uT)v \\&=& u(Tv) && \text{(Assuming this is true)}\\
&=& u \cdot [(a \otimes b)v] && \text{Definition of Tensor}\\
&=& u \cdot [(b\cdot v)a] && \text{Definition of Tensor product}\\
&=& [(b \cdot v)u]\cdot a && \text{Comutativity of the scalar} \\
&=& [(u \otimes b)v]\cdot a && \text{Definition of Tensor product} \\
&=& [Uv]\cdot a && \text{Definition of Tensor}
\end{align*}

Well, that doesn't seem very helpful, since now I must know this new tensor $U$ and also must know the vector $a$ that composes $T$ with the tensor product...

I guess I could also try visualizing the whole problem by mixing the matrix representation of tensors, but as an exercise of abstraction, I wanted to avoid doing this... Does someone have any suggestion or tip on how can I proceed to define such operation?

Comment: Before you go abstract and get lost in the way, it is better to start with some computed examples and then generalise. Perhaps you should give some explicit examples of $T, a, b$ and show how it acts on a column vector $u$.

Comment: I'm following your suggestion. For the most basic operations, it seems that the result of such operation $uT$ must be a vector $w$ (As it is when dealing with matrices). Also, the components of such $w$ seems to be $w_i = [w]_i = [u]^T_i \cdot [T]_{ji}$. I'll try to continue this tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Let $V$ and $W$ be some vector spaces: I would usually say that a tensor $T$ like you describe belongs to a vector space like $V \otimes W^*$, where $W^*$ is the dual of $W$. Then on an elementary tensor $v \otimes w^* \in V \otimes W$, the evaluation map is $W \to V$, $w_0 \mapsto w^*(w_0) v$, and this is how $Tw_0$ is defined. There was not really any right/left going on here, there was basically only one thing I could do. So, where does your tensor $T$ live, and what sort of object do you want to get out of $uT$?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess you are correct. I was thinking more about the matrices analogy, and maybe I shouldn't. My final though is that what I want is simply $u \cdot Tv = T^Tu \cdot v$, that is, I simply wanted to be able to operate over $u$ before operating over $v$, but in order to do that, I can make the transpose of the tensor and operate this new tensor over $v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  wanted to be able to operate over $u$ before operating over $v$. In order to do that, I believe it is possible to rewrite the equation like this:

$$
u \cdot Tv = T^Tu \cdot v
$$